# StreamBuilder snapshot always returns empty value and null safety error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

This is the code that I have implemented to get the data that can be seen on the home page of WhatsApp, i.e. the profile photo, name of the contact, last message, and the time sent of a Individual/Group Chat ListTile.

```
    return firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('chats')
        .snapshots()
        .asyncMap((event) async {
      List<ChatContact> contacts = [];
      for (var document in event.docs) {
        var chatContact = ChatContact.fromMap(document.data());

        var userData = await firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(chatContact.contactID)
            .get();

        var user = model.User.fromMap(userData.data()!);

        contacts.add(
          ChatContact(
            name: user.name,
            profilePic: user.photoURL,
            contactID: chatContact.contactID,
            timeSent: chatContact.timeSent,
            lastMessage: chatContact.lastMessage,
          ),
        );
      }

      return contacts;
    });
```

I am calling this in a StreamBuilder to get the list of the contacts in the following way:

```
 StreamBuilder<List<ContactList>>(
              stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).getchatContacts(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var chatContactData = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context, UserChatScreen.routeName,
                                    arguments: {
                                      'name': 'rr',
                                      'selectedContactUID': 'uid'
                                    });
                              },
                              child: const ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'name',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    ' lastMessage',
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://png.pngitem.com/pimgs/s/649-6490124_katie-notopoulos-katienotopoulos-i-write-about-tech-round.png',
                                  ),
                                  radius: 30,
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  'Date',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ))
                        ],
                      );
                    });
              }),
```

This is the error that I'm also facing right now:

**Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<List>'**

Comment: Cut out the problem. What do snapshots return? Do you have any data there? If yes then the problem is further. Repeat the operation until you find out where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return `ListView` with `data`, when snapshot still doesn't have `data`.

wrap the entire `ListView.builder` inside `if(snapshot.hasData)`

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
 return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var chatContactData = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context, UserChatScreen.routeName,
                                    arguments: {
                                      'name': 'rr',
                                      'selectedContactUID': 'uid'
                                    });
                              },
                              child: const ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'name',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    ' lastMessage',
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://png.pngitem.com/pimgs/s/649-6490124_katie-notopoulos-katienotopoulos-i-write-about-tech-round.png',
                                  ),
                                  radius: 30,
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  'Date',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ))
                        ],
                      );
                    });
}
return CircularProgressIndicator(); //  Add this line to return something when if condition is not met.
```